# "she" (always takes) or (has always taken) "good care of her finances"

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

the question is in "Common mistakes at CAE" ([amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521603773))

unit 1

the book says the answer is
*"she has always taken good care of her finances"*

but why can't I say *"she always takes good care of her finances"* ?

i imagine the context as being that she is very disciplined and careful with her finances and budget, always pays everything correctly and never lose control over her money.

i saw in google that you can "she always takes care of her younger siblings" for example
[Our Bodies, Their Battlefields: War Through the Lives of Women](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=fFj5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22she%20always%20takes%20care%20of%22&source=bl&ots=J3uHYpmC8U&sig=ACfU3U1OHJ8Zh71FgNgnUsLc5Q--7DRyxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirvtCVjZXwAhVIIbkGHX8sBVUQ6AEwCXoECAYQAw#v=onepage&q=%22she%20always%20takes%20care%20of%22&f=false)

sorry if the question is stupid... i'm trying my best ç - ç

============

the question in the book simply says "Complete the sentences with the correct form of the verb in brackets"

8 - She ___ (always / take) good care of her finances.

[here](https://assets.cambridge.org/97813166/29321/excerpt/9781316629321_excerpt.pdf) in the first page

Comment: Hello Votric. What is the question in the book, please? The answers mean different things. "She has always taken good care .. " means that all through her life she has taken good care. "She always takes good care" mean that she does take good care now, every time, but she may not have done so when she was younger.

Comment: the question in the book simply says "Complete the sentences with the correct form of the verb in brackets"

8 - She ___ (always / take) good care of her finances.

=====

[here](https://assets.cambridge.org/97813166/29321/excerpt/9781316629321_excerpt.pdf) in the first page

==========

i know that the unit is "perfect tense" and that all the answers use perfect tense, but i just want to understand better, because in exams and other situations i would not know if i use the perfect tense or not

but your explanation makes me understand better the case

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the book is asking for answers in the past tense. I agree that the answer is ambiguous with both "always takes" and "has always taken" being acceptable, but all the other sentences are in past tense, which suggests that is what it wants you to practice